# Get header value from http response in Typescript

Tags: typescript, api, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to access a new header I have added to my API response in TypeScript. In the Network tab of my developer tools, I can see that the new header I added is present, but when I try `req.headers.get("x-web-frontend-version")` I just get null.

Here is my code and image of my network tab:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let headers = req.headers;

    console.log('HEADERS: ' + headers.get('x-web-frontend-version'));

    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: headers
    });

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Could it be that req.headers are the headers of the request but x-web-frontend-version are headers of a response?

Comment: I do believe that it the case, do you know how I would go about getting the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the function Intercept is in some service file, such as `some.service.ts`, in the component file, `some.component.ts`, I would try the following:

```
const xWebFrontednVersion: string;
this.someService.intercept(req, next).toPromise().then(response => {
        this.xWebFrontednVersion = response.headers.get('x-web-frontend-version');
})
```